# Highmaps - prevent colorAxis numbers to overlap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I have a problem with the colorAxis on a map i've created.The numbers are overlapping and I would like to have some help styling them differenly in order to prevent that from happening.

This is the code for the colorAxis:

```
  colorAxis: {
        maxColor: '#7b9b00',
        minColor: '#d7e241',
        type: 'linear',
        allowDecimals: false,
        marker: {
          color: 'black'
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return this.value;
          }
        }
      },
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image: overlapping numbers in colorAxis]

Comment: Are you at all considering not actually supplying a formatter for the labels? The default one uses prefixes "M", "G"... to shorten the values enough to have them all showing.

Comment: You can play with the tick options or label options such as staggerLines, step, tickAmount to adjust the number of ticks and labels. http://jsfiddle.net/s10fd5pL/1/. See documentation for those options http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.labels.staggerLines